# Some of the APIs are not accessible of IBM cloud storage object S3 API

Tags: api, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am referring information on following url.
https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/about-compatibility-api#operations-on-buckets
As mentioned in above URL,there are 3 Objects related IBM cloud storage object API which  are accessible.However,some APIs of IBM CSO API are not accessible  e.g. PUT Bucket ACL & GET Bucket ACL and getting 403 error message while accessing them with POSTMAN.I need information that how can we access these APIs? Please provide any information related to it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, GET/PUT Bucket ACL are supported in IBM COS.  If you are using Postman, here's an example of a Postman dump for these (obviously you'll need to calculate the `Authorization` header and use all of your own info, this is just an educational sample):

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "collections": [
        {
            "id": "ab20b534-025a-4be2-b90f-a980d4a81632",
            "name": "Operations on buckets",
            "folders": [],
            "requests": [
                {
                    "id": "b89a66a4-0183-43cf-9712-7c07ba615b0b",
                    "url": "http://endpoint/bucket-name?acl=",
                    "method": "PUT",
                    "collectionId": "ab20b534-025a-4be2-b90f-a980d4a81632",
                    "name": "Add a bucket ACL (canned)",
                    "description": "",
                    "headers": "x-amz-date: {timestamp}\nAuthorization: {authorization-string}\nx-amz-acl: public-read\nContent-Type: text/plain",
                    "dataMode": "raw",
                    "data": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": "df2a9b2a-d66b-4ea6-8cfb-ab341ec23bc2",
                    "url": "http://endpoint/bucket-name?acl=",
                    "method": "PUT",
                    "collectionId": "ab20b534-025a-4be2-b90f-a980d4a81632",
                    "name": "Add a bucket ACL (custom)",
                    "description": "",
                    "headers": "x-amz-date: {timestamp}\nx-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\nAuthorization: {authorization-string}\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataMode": "raw",
                    "data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<AccessControlPolicy xmlns=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/\">\n  <Owner>\n    <ID>d4d11b981e6e489486a945d640d41c4d</ID>\n    <DisplayName>OwnerDisplayName1</DisplayName>\n  </Owner>\n  <AccessControlList>\n    <Grant>\n      <Grantee xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\">\n        <ID>d4d11b981e6e489486a945d640d41c4d</ID>\n        <DisplayName>some-name</DisplayName>\n      </Grantee>\n      <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>\n    </Grant>\n    <Grant>\n      <Grantee xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\">\n        <ID>a5c26620b0704967a72d7aeb90cf57b2</ID>\n        <DisplayName>some-name</DisplayName>\n      </Grantee>\n      <Permission>WRITE</Permission>\n    </Grant>\n  </AccessControlList>\n</AccessControlPolicy>"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7f79523f-b9aa-46ad-abda-9ad7e37d3980",
                    "url": "http://bucket-name.endpoint/?acl=",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "collectionId": "ab20b534-025a-4be2-b90f-a980d4a81632",
                    "name": "Get a bucket ACL",
                    "description": "",
                    "headers": "x-amz-date: {timestamp}\nAuthorization: {authorization-string}\nContent-Type: text/plain",
                    "dataMode": "raw",
                    "data": ""
                }
            ],
            "order": [
                "b89a66a4-0183-43cf-9712-7c07ba615b0b",
                "df2a9b2a-d66b-4ea6-8cfb-ab341ec23bc2",
                "7f79523f-b9aa-46ad-abda-9ad7e37d3980"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": "fa619322-0a84-47b5-958b-84fa4a6286ba",
            "name": "API-Flow Imports",
            "values": [],
            "timestamp": 1497532748923
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on your reference to the 'Cloud Storage Object API', I can guess you might be working with an on-premises installation of IBM COS. Please send me an email at nicholas.lange[at]ibm.com so we can discuss what you are looking for.